# How to write a java code for crawling sites with apache nutch 1.3 api?

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

I want to write a program with java and nutch 1.3 api to crawl the the sites
i searched the web but there is no sample code 
how can i do that?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well you don't need to write any Java code to that... just install Nutch and off you go. However you should install Nutch 1.2 which is self contained.
With Nutch1.3 you need to install hadoop yourself and you need to install & user Solr for the webseach too.

Comment: i already write a java program with solrj api to index my files localy and have control and debug on it, but i dont know is it possible for nutch?

Comment: nutch based on hadoop indexes URLs not file system